# Random curves in JS chart line graph by amCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, amcharts, jscharts

I am facing a strange behaviour of line graph (using amCharts library). I am passing pretty straight forward data array to create chart while the chart draws some random curves anywhere in the trend line. The data i am passing is exactly :

```
{date: "2016-02-17", value2: "2.00"}
{date: "2016-03-17", value2: "2.00"}
{date: "2017-01-17", value2: "4.33"}
{date: "2017-02-17", value2: "4.33"}
{date: "2017-07-17", value2: "3.20"}
{date: "2017-08-17", value2: "3.20"}
```

and the graph i get with this data is shown in the attached image. What can be the problem here?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's a bug when using the `smoothedLine` graph type with date-based data. It's being looked at but a workaround you can try is setting `equalSpacing` to true in the `categoryAxis`

```
categoryAxis: {
  // ...
  equalSpacing: true,
  // ...
}
```

This usually fixes the issue at the expense of changing how your categoryAxis looks with `equalSpacing` enabled. If it still doesn't help, you'll have to resort to using the regular `line` type until it gets fixed.

Comment: Well i needed the smooth line graph and equalSpacing is ruining my graph so still waiting if some better option or solution comes.

Comment: Unfortunately it's going to be a while before it gets fixed. Sorry. If we make any progress, I'll remember to ping you through this thread.